# Segfault with PHP fread() on text file over 2GB

Tags: php

I have a php script which reads in a text file and does a count of all the lines in the file which match a specified regular expression. The script has worked well up until now as it segfaulted on the fread of a file over 2GB.

Actually before the segfault, I initially received the PHP Fatal Error: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2223941409 bytes).

To fix that I added this line to my script: ini_set('memory_limit', '4G');
That fixes the memory size exhausted error but I get the segfault on fread now.

Here's a condensed working version of the script which will exhibit the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '4G');
$file = $argv[1];
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
$fsize = filesize($file);
print("SIZE: ".$fsize."\n" );
$myData = fread($fh, $fsize);
print("Got passed fread!\n");
fclose($fh);
preg_match_all( '/Z\t/', $myData, $sArray );
$scount = count($sArray,COUNT_RECURSIVE);
print("COUNT: ".$scount."\n");
?>
```

Sample output:

```
$ runtest.php testfile.txt
SIZE: 2223941408
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Other info:

OS: CentOS release 6.7 (Final) x86_64

PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2015 17:39:00)  64-bit

Comment: The last times i had same problem with CentOS and PHP. My Webserver ran in some Segmentation faults. Now i changed to Ubuntu and have no problems. I have found some tickets but all with open fixes.

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit PHP distribution?

Comment: Using 64-bit PHP: PHP_INT_SIZE is 8

Comment: What if you finish your script before preg_match_all? Maybe that function has a failing code?. On the other hand, why are you loading 2gb file into memory? Best practice is to read line by line.

Comment: I inserted some print statements and it never gets passed the fread, that line is causing the segfault. I didn't see a size limit specified for fread in the manual. Regardless loading the whole thing into memory isn't ideal so I'll rewrite that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi 2GB means that there is some internal 32-bit limitation in PHP. Are you running 32-bit PHP?

There is an alternative solution. You can do it with a very small memory overhead using a shell command called by PHP. The memory used would be no more than a couple of MB as grep and wc only load portions of the file into memory.

```
$lines = shell_exec("grep 'Z\t' $file | wc --lines");
```

grep: command to search files using regular expression

wc: command that returns the number of words/lines/chars

Comment: I'm running 64-bit PHP. Thanks for the alternative solution suggestion, that works and it more efficient than loading the entire file into memory as I did with the fread.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a 32-bit PHP distribution. Under such architecture a PHP process cannot allocate more than 2 GB of RAM. In practice the upper limit is closer to 1GB than 2GB—the interpreter crashes way before getting to the 2 GB limit. Additionally, integer variables cannot be greater than [PHP_INT_MAX](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max) which, in 32 builds, is as small as 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>32</sup>-1).

This highlights two problems in your code:

```
$fsize = filesize($file);
```

... [will not work](http://php.net/filesize) if the file size is greater that `PHP_INT_MAX`.

> Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB.

```
$myData = fread($fh, $fsize);
```

... will crash for large files because you're loading the complete file contents in memory and then doing additional processing that will probably eat even more memory.

You'd better redesign your algorithm and read the file in small chunks (the task where `fread()` excels at). Counting the occurrences of a two-character substring should only need a few KB of RAM.

Here's a possible approach that assumes single byte encoding (as your code does):

```
// Ridiculously small value for illustration purposes, set to something bigger for better performance
define('CHUNK_SIZE', 4); 

$fsize = $scount = 0;
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
$possible_pending_match = false;
while (!feof($fh)) {
    $chunk = fread($fh, CHUNK_SIZE);
    $fsize += strlen($chunk);
    $scount += substr_count($chunk, "Z\t");
    if ($possible_pending_match && $chunk[0]==="\t") {
        $scount++;
    }
    $possible_pending_match = substr($chunk, -1)==='Z';
}
print("SIZE: ".$fsize."\n" );
print("COUNT: ".$scount."\n");
print("MEMORY: ".memory_get_peak_usage(true)." bytes\n");
```

You'd need to add 1 to `$scount` to get the same result as your code, which counts one extra item for no evident reason—it feels like a bug but I don't know the specs.

Comment: I'm actually usge 64bit PHP: PHP_INT_SIZE is 8, PHP_INT_MAX is 9223372036854775807. The SIZE returned in my sample output is actually the correct size of the file.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I still believe though that the segfault is memory related (a regexp match on a 2GB string is still extremely resource intensive). I've updated my answer with a code sample.